# jQuery Get ID based on Class, write to HTML and fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, fadein

I've been having an issue getting this working.

I am able to get the ID based on the Class of a div, and output it to the screen, but I cannot get the fadeIn method to work on the same div.

here is what I have so far at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y8Ara/1/

and here is the jQuery:

```
$('.courseLink').mouseover(function() {
    $('div#courseTitle').text(this.id);
});
```

If at all possible, I would also like to make the text fade out on mouseout as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

***SOLVED: Thanks to Adil & roasted! I have also added the fadeOut functionality if anyone else was wondering - http://jsfiddle.net/Y8Ara/17/***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be done like this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8Ara/17/)

```
$('.courseLink').hover(function() {
    $('div#courseTitle').hide().fadeIn().text(this.id);
},function(){
     $('div#courseTitle').stop().fadeOut();
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like:

```
$('.courseLink').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $('div#courseTitle').hide().text(this.id).fadeIn("slow");
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $('div#courseTitle').text('');
    }        
});
```